# Convert stored procedure to table-valued query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, stored-functions, sql-function

I have this procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].GetHerdByUserProc(@user int)
As 
    begin
        Declare
            @GroupId uniqueidentifier,
            @UserTrade bit

        Set @GroupId = (select tbUser.group_id from tbUser where Userid = @user)
        Set @UserTrade = (select tbUser.isTrade from tbUser where Userid = @user)
        if @GroupId IS NOT NULL and @UserTrade = '1'
        Begin 
            select HerdId from tbUserHerds where tbUserHerds.UserId in (select Userid from tbUser where tbUser.Group_Id = @GroupId)
            return;
        END
        If @GroupId IS NOT NULL
        Begin   
            select HerdId from tbUserHerds where tbUserHerds.UserId = @user
            return;
        End
        return;
    End
```

It returns a list correctly except I would also like to run a query on the list that is returned and as far as I am aware I cannot write a query such as

```
Select * from GetHerdByUserProc 80
```

So I am looking the best way to convert this to a table-valued query.

I have changed the alter to say `'Create Function x(@user int) Returns Table As'`

But that does not seam to work it starts screaming errors at me.

Any ideas?  The Database Server is MSSQL2008

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... stuff like this is highly vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your Syntax, I'm going to assume SQL Server for now.

From [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) the Syntax for an inline function should be...

```
--Transact-SQL Inline Table-Valued Function Syntax 
CREATE FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name 
( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ] [ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type 
    [ = default ] [ READONLY ] } 
    [ ,...n ]
  ]
)
RETURNS TABLE
    [ WITH <function_option> [ ,...n ] ]
    [ AS ]
    RETURN [ ( ] select_stmt [ ) ]
[ ; ]
```

With this format, you ***can not*** use `SET, DECLARE, IF, etc`.  All you can use is a single SQL Statement.  *[If you **need** to use program flow, look to a multi-statement table valued function.]*

It's a separate topic, but Inline Table Valued Functions have *many* performance efficiencies over their Multi-Statement equivilents.  Nearly always, if you can do it Inline, you should do so.

As it happens, you can write your logic without the `IF` statements, and use just a single SQL Statement.  This gives the following Inline Table Valued Function...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].GetHerdByUserProc(@user int)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
  SELECT
    herd.HerdID
  FROM
    tbUser          AS user
  INNER JOIN
    tbUser          AS group
      ON group.group_id = user.group_id
  INNER JOIN
    tbUserHerds     AS herd
      ON herd.UserID = group.UserID
  WHERE
        user.userID   = @userID
    AND user.isTrade  = 1
    AND user.group_id IS NOT NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    herd.HerdID
  FROM
    tbUser          AS user
  INNER JOIN
    tbUserHerds     AS herd
      ON herd.UserID = user.UserID
  WHERE
        user.userID    = @userID
    AND user.isTrade  <> 1
    AND user.group_id IS NOT NULL
```

The `UNION ALL` combined with the `WHERE` clauses effectively does your `IF` statements for you.  *(Do note, if user.isTrade can be `NULL`, you need to change `user.isTrade <> 1` to something more like `ISNULL(user.isTrade, 0) <> 1`.)*

Potentially, you could even simplify this down to a single query, though I would test it to see if it's actually any more efficient or not...

```
RETURN
  SELECT
    herd.HerdID
  FROM
    tbUser          AS user
  INNER JOIN
    tbUser          AS group
      ON (group.group_id = user.group_id AND user.isTrade = 1)
      OR (group.user_id  = user.userID)
  INNER JOIN
    tbUserHerds     AS herd
      ON herd.UserID = group.UserID
  WHERE
    user.userID = @userID
```

- if `group_id` is NULL, the first join will never succeed.
- then the two IF blocks are simulated by the `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the results of the PROC in a temp table:

```
INSERT INTO #temptbl EXEC [dbo].GetHerdByUserProc(80)
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? Storing the results of the sp into a temp table will allow the OP to run queries against the result-set, without having to rewrite the code.

Comment: It doesn't need to be an SP, the OP doesn't want an SP, you can't call an SP from within a SQL Statment, so it's harder to join itself to itself *(as well as a lot of other lost functionality)*, this can only be done at one level of the SP call tree *(if an outer SP also uses this trick, it will fail)*. Mostly, the fact that it doesn't answer the OPs question, when it is perfectly answerable, and perfectly reasonable, and even recommended, that's why I'm adding your second -1. *[You don't even explain WHY this should be used in your answer, though your comment does go towards that.]*

Comment: The OP clearly states: "As far as i know I cannot use something like "Select * from GetHerdByUserProc 80". My answer shows that there is a way to accomplish what he wants, without the need to rewrite everything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the structure of the table in the definition and then insert values into the declare table variable...

```
create function x
(
    @user int 
)
returns @t
( 
   herdid int
)
as
begin
    insert @t (herdid)
    select HerdId from tbUserHerds where tbUserHerds.UserId = @user
    -- or whatever...
    return 
end
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: True for `multi-statement` TVFs.  I would explicitly state that `Inline` TVFs are different, and have different restrictions and benefits.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write sql query using CASE statement . CASE statement is easiest way to handle Conditional Queries .

```
 Declare @GroupId uniqueidentifier,@UserTrade bit

 select HerdId 
 from tbUserHerds 
 where 
 1 = CASE 
    WHEN (select tbUser.group_id from tbUser where Userid = @user) IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 
        CASE 
            WHEN tbUserHerds.UserId = @user THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END

    WHEN 
            (select tbUser.group_id from tbUser where Userid = @user) IS NOT NULL      and           (select tbUser.isTrade from tbUser where Userid = @user) = '1'
    THEN 
        CASE 
            WHEN tbUserHerds.UserId in (select Userid from tbUser     where tbUser.Group_Id = (select tbUser.group_id from tbUser where Userid = @user)) THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END
END
```